# override an intent filter android

Tags: android, android-intent

I followed Damian Flannery's Blog [Integrate zxing barcode scanner into your Android app natively using Eclipse](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse) and now have a working barcode scanner within my app.

However I noted that after comments from Sean Owen that Damian had added some extra comments :

"... make sure that override your intent filters so that other apps that want to use zxing do not end up calling your modified version. Also, if zxing is already installed, then you should use that by default instead of your modified version."

Can anyone help me in understanding how to override an intent filter and how to make sure the an installed version of zxing is used in preference to my modified version.